# SQL Server 2005-data count

Tags: sql-server-2005

hi i created project using asp.net and sql server 2005.I created table and inserted datainto sqlserver 2005. but i dont how to find the(count) number of records stored in the table.how to find this?

Comment: [Start here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
SELECT COUNT(PrimaryKeyColumn) FROM YoutTableName
```

Never use Count(*).

Also, you can use sysindexes table to get the row count of a table. Read [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1044).

Comment: @Ashish: I'm interested to know why you say "never use count(*)", what basis do you have for saying that? Here's a related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Comment: @Tony, thanks. Will strikeout when I am done analysing.
There is a table in my db which has 136001 rec and I ran the following on it
 DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
go

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM base
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base
SET STATISTICS IO OFF 

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'Base'. Scan count 1, logical reads 673, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 669, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Base'. Scan count 1, logical reads 673, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <YOURTABLE>
```